# Compilation failed when installing R package ‘statnet.common’

Tags: r, compiler-errors, compilation, quanteda

I'm trying to install the R package `quanteda` for use on my university's computational cluster. When I try, I get an error message about one of the dependencies, `statnet.common`. When I try to install `statnet.common` dirrectly, it gives me several error messages that all refer to problems with for loops only being allowed in C99 mode. An example:

> logspace_utils.c:167:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
>        for(unsigned int k = 0; k <= j; k++){
>        ^ make: *** [logspace_utils.o] Error 1

At the end, it gives me the following error message:

> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘statnet.common’

Based on related problems I've found when searching this site and others, I've tried adding "-std=c99" to the CXX14 line in the Makevars file, but this doesn't help the problem. In case it helps, the version of R on the cluster is 3.6.2, and the operating system is Unix.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Really hard to know here since you don't include the Linux distribution, or of the quanteda version you are trying to install. **statnet.common** is not a direct dependency in **quanteda**, so I'm unfamiliar with that problem, but it sounds the like difficulty is there.

Comment: After checking I believe the Linux version is 3.10.0. The direct dependency of **quanteda** that requires **statnet.common** is **sna**.

Comment: I meant what distribution of Linux. Anyway sometimes on Linux, installing dependencies manually, separately, works better. Try installing **sna**, and if that fails, **statnet.common**, separately before installing **quanteda**.